# How to add a new item to p-breadcrum list?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to add a new item to p-breadcrumb list on click event, but my code doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-breadcrumb-demo-ncapwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
        {label: 'Computer'},
        {label: 'Notebook'},
        {label: 'Accessories'},
        {label: 'Backpacks'},
        {label: 'Item'}
    ];
    
    this.home = {icon: 'pi pi-home'};
}

addItem(){
    this.items.push({label: 'testing'})
}
```

Comment: Using spread operator, like: `this.items = [...this.items, {label: 'Item'}]` instead of `push`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is adding, but you are not seeing the updates on the page.
Replace the way you are visualizing the data in the template for it:

```
<label *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.label}}
</label>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-breadcrumb-demo-ncapwe?file=src/app/app.component.html

Also, right after using the "push" console log the array, you will be able to see that the data is correct.

Comment: I also put a new method printArray, so right after you add a new item click it and check the console.